# How do I access sub-components of a list field in OpenERP 7?

Tags: xml, odoo, openerp-7, extending

If you go to the details page for a product and click on the "*Procurements*" tab, you'll see a list label "*Suppliers*".

Looking at the XML for the page, the only field I can see in this location is "*seller_ids*". However, the list also shows "*Delivery Lead Time*" and "*Minimal Quantity*".

Are these fields somehow contained within "*seller_ids*", like an array?

I can't find any other views that add the other fields. I would like to add "*Product Name*" and "*Product Code*" to the list.

I believe all of the fields are in the "*product.supplierinfo*" model.  How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the product.product model you will see the seller_ids is a one2many field.

When OpenERP encounters this, it looks at the model this o2m field represents and then retrieve the tree view for it and display it so the fields you are seeing are coming from the tree view for the seller model (product.supplierinfo from memory).  Behind the scenes, OpenERP returns a list of the records from the seller table related to that product based on the foreign key.

If you want to amend this you have two options.

1. Change the tree view for the seller model.  The downside is this effects everywhere this tree view is displayed unless you start mucking about with contexts and over-riding methods.
2. Inherit the view and embed a tree view inside the field so the XML becomes:

The upside is the change only affects the one form and you can customise it however you want.  The downside is some duplication as you now have two tree views for the seller model, the main one and this nested one but in practice this isn't really a problem.